# Other element would receive the click error

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

How do you click the cart icon if the error says element is not clickable?
I already tried it using inspect element but to no avail. I've been doing this for hour and I still don't get how to click the cart icon. If that's not the element of cart icon, then what is it? Thanks so much. I am pretty new to stackoverflow.

```
driver.get("http://www.metromart.com");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".hover-green")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ember781")).sendKeys("deumdummy@yahoo.com");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ember783")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn.green.block")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@style,'background-image: url(https://metromart3.imgix.net/shops/5/logo.png?ixlib=rb-1.0.0)')]")).click();

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.green.medium"));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Acana Duck And Bartlett Pear Singles Formula']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn.green.huge.block")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ember-view.cart-icon")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".btn.green.jumbo]")));
```

Comment: Have you tried the wait with condition as clickable? if not please try

Comment: Wrap click operation inside `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(elementToWait)` wait condition. Also make sure that you are clicking the right element (so that it is NOT hidden field or no elements are above it).

Comment: In which line have you the problem??

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions
    .presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".ember-view.cart-icon")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ember-view.cart-icon")).click();
```

Comment: Can you use that twice? do I just need to replace the webelements?

Comment: Probably the wait part is the problem. I had used the same Webelement that you had used, just added the wait part.